# using python, Search for a text and print next few lines in python

Tags: python-3.x

Currently I am new to Python 3.x coding and looking for some help in text search.

I have large file with more than 8000 lines and need to find a text within this file.Once text found, need subsequent 3 lines along with (text)line redirected to new file.

Any help in this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should post code on what you have attempted. I suggest trying the following functions methods. `str.find('text') open(filename, 'r') readline()`

Comment: @StevenSummers Thanks. I'm learning and try to tweak my work so appreciated your help. Any suggestion in how to parse input and then search in the file. Once found need current and next few lines in other file.                                                                                         name = input('Enter file:')
with open(name) as f:
    with open("output.txt", "w") as f1:
        for line in f:
            if flag:
                f1.write(line + '\n')
                flag = False
            if _input from user_ in line:
                f1.write(line)
                flag = True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method which opens up output file for appending every time match is found:

```
search_string = 'search'
with open('infile.txt', mode='r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if search_string in line:
            with open('outfile.txt', mode='a') as outfile:
                outfile.writelines([line, next(infile), next(infile)])
```

Method which opens up output file for writing at the same time as input file is opened and closes out file at the same time input file is closed.

```
search_string = 'search'
with open('infile.txt', 'r') as infile, open('outfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        if search_string in line:
            outfile.writelines([line, next(infile), next(infile)])
```

The `next(infile)` bits iterate over the next line in the file.  This should work for other iterators as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well when you find that line in file you should be able to do just file.readline() to get next lines. (You should use .find() for string search, this is just quick example).

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as infile:
for line in infile:
    if 'myString' in line:
        line2 = infile.readline()
        line3 = infile.readline()
        print(line, end="")
        print(line2, end="")
        print(line3, end="")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can I parse input from user or other file instead of "mystring" and redirect the output in other file.